# Is there a Math.floorDiv(a, b), but for BigInteger?

Tags: java

Some way to make a `Math.floorDiv(a, b);` and return the floor division of two BigInteger values

**An example:**

```java
BigInteger big0 = new BigInteger("10");
BigInteger big1 = new BigInteger("20");
Math.floorDiv(big0, big1);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Switch to `BigDecimal` and you can control rounding. A scale of `0` means the results are rounded to an integer and `FLOOR` rounds towards negative infinity.

```
big0.divide(big1, 0, RoundingMode.FLOOR)
```

(If you construct `big0` from an `int`, `long`, or `BigInteger` then its scale will already be `0` and you can omit the middle argument.)

Answer (score 2):

No such method exists in the `BigInteger` API.

However, you could implement it using `BigInteger::divideAndRemainder` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#divideAndRemainder(java.math.BigInteger))) and adjusting the result to be analogous to the `Math::floorDiv` spec.  Something like this:

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("10");
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("20");

BigInteger c = floorDiv(a, b);

public BigInteger floorDiv(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    // divideAndRemainder returns quotient and remainder in array
    BigInteger[] qr = a.divideAndRemainder(b);  
    return qr[0].signum() >= 0 || qr[1].signum() == 0 ? 
         qr[0] : qr[0].subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Comment: Hang on, this doesn't seem right. Why is the signum of `qr[0]` being checked? This code returns 0 for `floorDiv(-1, 2)`, but it should be `-1`. As far as I can tell `qr[1].signum() >= 0 ? qr[0] : qr[0].subtract(BigInteger.ONE);` produces correct results, but SO isn't letting me edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Math.floorDiv`:

```
public static BigInteger floorDiv(final BigInteger x, final BigInteger y) {
    if (x.signum() * y.signum() >= 0) {
        return x.divide(y);
    }
    final BigInteger[] qr = x.divideAndRemainder(y);
    return qr[1].signum() == 0 ? qr[0] : qr[0].subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```